# How do I validate the data for a Laravel 5 model in a artisan command?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have a command that fetches data from an API and push it to my local database using an artisan command. As it's a command, I don't have a Request.

How do I validate the model data? I need to check if the description has only 10 characters and if the due_at date is greater than today.

Rely on database validation is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation doesn't need a request object.  You can pass any array as the first parameter here:

```
$validator = Validator::make([
    'title' => 'This is too long',
    'body' => 'Hello world!'
], [
    'title' => 'required|max:10',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```